# how to Substrate 36 hours from date field in database

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i display a range of date from my Date field in the database into a table?
I have a field called: Date from the database that Display the event date of 5 days. And I would like to display only 1 day and 12 hours (36 hours) using SQL Statement.
 Field name : date, details from Events_new table. This table display 5 days of date and time records. and It's updates automatically. **My point is that I need a SQL Query that will fetch the last 36 hours from the table**

I tried many time. This is my SQl Statement but I can't get it right.

```
   SELECT 
    details , datediff(date , interval 36 hour) as substratehours
FROM
    events_new
WHERE
    Stuff_id = 4932
order by date ASC
```

And This :

```
SELECT 
   date,
    details
FROM
    events_new
WHERE
    stuff_id = 4932
AND date = (date - interval 36 hour)
```

And This:

```
SELECT 
   date,
    details
FROM
    events_new
WHERE
    stuff_id = 4932
AND date > date_sub(date,interval 36 hour)

order by date ASC
```

**I Still Don't get it right! Anyone with a subjection?**

Thank you

Comment: Your question is not clear. Add some sample data from your database (only the relevant fields of several rows) and the result set you want to get.

Comment: `date > date_sub(date, interval 36 hour)` always evaluates to `TRUE`. It can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the rows having `date` in the most recent 36 hours only:

```
SELECT details
FROM events_new
WHERE Stuff_id = 4932
  AND `date` > date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 36 HOUR)
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

If you don't want the 36 hours interval to end now but at some arbitrary moment in time then you should use `BETWEEN` to compare the value of field `date` with the interval bounds:

```
SELECT details
FROM events_new
WHERE Stuff_id = 4932
  AND `date` BETWEEN date_sub('2015-01-19 12:00:00', INTERVAL 36 HOUR)
             AND '2015-01-19 12:00:00' 
ORDER BY `date` ASC
```

Replace `'2015-01-19 12:00:00'` with the moment when you want your 36 hours interval ends.

Take a look at MySQL documentation about the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) statement and [date & time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: Thank a lot That will help! let me take a look at your link.

Answer (score 1):

In mysql

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL -36 hour) AS date from  events_new
```

In mssql

```
 select DATEADD(hour , -36 , date )AS date from  events_new
```

Comment: Your first query Gives me more than 5000 records. And that's not what I need to see. And your second one is Blank with Error return. Thanks